# Python Youtube API: upload function not working

Tags: python, upload, youtube, youtube-api

I want to create an application that allows user to upload video to Youtube.
Here is the code I tried (adapted from http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/tests/gdata_tests/youtube/service_test.py):

```
my_media_group = gdata.media.Group(
                                       title = gdata.media.Title(text=title),
                                       description = gdata.media.Description(description_type='plain',
                                                                             text=description),
                                       keywords = gdata.media.Keywords(text= tags),
                                       category = gdata.media.Category(
                                                                       text='Autos',
                                                                       scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat',
                                                                       label='Autos'),
                                       player=None
    )
    # Set Geo location to 37,-122 lat, long
    where = gdata.geo.Where()
    where.set_location((37.0,-122.0))
    video_entry = gdata.youtube.YouTubeVideoEntry(media=my_media_group, geo=where)
    print "Creating a video entry: done."
    print "Uploading video"
    new_entry = self.client.InsertVideoEntry(video_entry, filepath)
    print "Done uploading video."
```

It always gets stuck at the second last line:

```
new_entry = self.client.InsertVideoEntry(video_entry, filepath)
```

So what's wrong? Is there any requirement about filepath (for example, is the path 'C:\video.avi' valid?)

In fact, I just need a way to upload, so please suggest any possible solution.

Edit: 1. I tried to embbed Youtube Upload widget, but it does not seem to work: (there is only one option to load from webcam, and that does not work either.)

```
<iframe id="widget" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/upload_embed" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

2. I use a QWebview to load Youtube' upload page, but Youtube always returns an error.
   [QWebview: Upload to Youtube return error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778169/qwebview-upload-to-youtube-return-error)

Edit 2:

I changed the code to:

```
def getYtSession(self, email = '', password =''):
    # if we do not want to reuse our session.
    if email != '' and password != '':
        yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
        yt_service.email = email
        yt_service.password = password

        #login.
        try:
            print yt_service.ProgrammaticLogin()
            self.email = email
            self.password = password
            self.logged_in = True
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('doneLogin(QString)'), QtCore.QString(email + " " + password))
            return yt_service
        except:
            #Display a warning dialog.
            self.logged_in = False
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('failedLogin()'))
            return None      
    elif self.yt_service: # we want to reuse the session.
        return self.yt_service
    else:
        return gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
```

and in upload function:

```
self.yt_service = self.getYtSession(self.email, self.password)
    try:
        new_entry = self.yt_service.InsertVideoEntry(video_entry, filepath)
        print "Done uploading video."
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('doneUpload(QString)'), QtCore.QString('Title: ' + title + '\nPath: ' + filepath))
    except:
        print "Stack trace:"
        traceback.print_stack()
```

It still does not work. And one more problem: the stack trace give nothing helpful:

```
Stack trace:Login successfully.
```

File "D:\workplace\simple-media-player\trunk\MyPlayer\src\QtThread.py", line 19, in run
    self.function(*self.args,**self.kwargs)
  File "D:\workplace\simple-media-player\trunk\MyPlayer\src\videoplayer.py", line 490, in doRealUpload
    traceback.print_stack()

That message ("Login successfully.") is printed by a function invoked when the signal doneLogin(QString) is emitted. If I do not put

```
new_entry = self.yt_service.InsertVideoEntry(video_entry, filepath)
        print "Done uploading video."
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('doneUpload(QString)'), QtCore.QString('Title: ' + title + '\nPath: ' + filepath))
```

in a try-except, then it prints nothing.

More info: I set the video information as follow:
Path: C:/Users/huynh/Desktop/REcord1.wmv
Name: 'A test video'
Tag: 'test, youtube'
Description: fafafa

Comment: When you say "it gets stuck," do you have the error code that Python returns on that line? Another thing to look at is where you created your Youtube Service Object (and what you called it, and whether or not its authentication was successful) -- does everything work with the creation of that before getting to the upload method?

Comment: InsertVideoEntry() is the API call that actually uploads the file. If you have a large video file and a slow uplink connection, it could take quite a while for the transfer to complete. The fact that you don't get a response back also means it's likely that this is just a slow upload. You can try uploading the same video file via the YouTube web interface and see how long it takes you.

Comment: @jlmcdonal: I cannot see any problem with the login process. I tried to save yt_service after login successfully to self.yt_service, but it did not work so I recreate it (successfully) as the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, never mind. I modified the code at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/tests/gdata_tests/youtube/service_test.py and it works perfectly!