# How to use Youtube's V3 API to upload videos directly using Python?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am working on a web application that involves uploading videos to YouTube. I have a working version that uploads videos to my server first, and then to YouTube.

While I was researching this, I found that it was possible to upload directly to YouTube, instead of first to my server. I believe this is known as browser based uploading. However, this seems like a feature just for the Version 2 API, and not for the Version 3 API, as I have not found anything like this for the Version 3 API. Is there a way to do this using the Version 3 API?

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: I would just like to clarify that I am using Python. I have found a JavaScript example of this (https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/yt-upload-javascript/index.js), but nothing similar for Python.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845084/python-youtube-api-upload-function-not-working

Comment: does "directly" means "from url"?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this ?

[github.com/tokland/youtube-upload](https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload/blob/master/youtube_upload/upload_video.py)

[Project Readme](https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: this project is APIv1. The new project is here: https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload/blob/master/youtube_upload/upload_video.py

Comment: @Kariem keeping the links fresh!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the python sample for YouTube Data Api v3 Upload
https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/upload_video.py

Comment: Yup that's what I was using. Do you know if there is a way to upload directly to YouTube (without going through a server)?